# how to stick an element on page (position: fixed) after it has been displayed?

Tags: jquery, growlnotify

I'm developing a growl like notifications for my site, currently it's like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="growls"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#growls {
position: fixed;
right: 20px;
bottom: 20px;
}

.growl {
display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
function growl(message) {
    if (growls < 5) {
        growls = growls + 1;
        $('<div class="growl short block">' + message + '</div>').prependTo('#growls').fadeIn('slow').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow', function() { growls = growls - 1 });
        }
    }
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/exonal)

It basically put new 'growl' on top of existing ones, problem is, when old ones disappear, new 'growls' suddenly collapse down, very annoying if you are reading the message.

I'm thinking about making the new growl div position fixed after it display, but it's not very clean (tons of adding and subtracting from elements offset)

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: The English in the question is perfectly good, no need to worry.

Comment: It is not very clear how you position your 'growls' inside the fixed box. Can you make an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a live example for you.

Comment: @unclenorton: I prepend new '.growl' in front of all others, so it will be added on top of others (top as in top of your monitor, no overlapping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it doesn't answer the exact question asked, but my suggestion would be to use `slideUp` to hide the elements instead of `fadeOut`.  This will give a nice fluid movement for the other elements to move into their new position.  This can easily be followed by the readers eye and won't cause the elements to jump.

Or for an even nicer look, use `animate` and animate the height and the opacity:

http://jsbin.com/exonal/4

```
$('<div class="growl short block">' + message + '</div>').prependTo('#growls')
    .fadeIn('slow').delay(2000)
    .animate({opacity: 0, height:"hide"},'slow', function() { growls = growls - 1 });
```

Comment: oh nice, I changed the animation to this and it look clearly better, I'll use it for now until I find a way to make them stick. I still prefer them staying still.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    // what is your jQuery version? this only works in 1.7+ otherwise use .delegate()
// register a hide show command for every .growl from page load and into the future.
       $("#growl").on("growlHideShow",".growl",{delayTime:2000}, function(event){
//slideToggle and fadeToggle are great.  change your display effect here with whatever you decide.
         $(this).slideToggle('slow');
         if($(this).is(":visible")){
//hide it after the 'delaytime' has passed.
           $(this).delay(event.data.delayTime).triggerHandler("growlHideShow");
         }
       });
    });

    function growl(message) {
    var growlDiv = $("#growl");
    var growlsList = $(".growls", growlDiv );
    var html = '<div class="growl short block">'+message+'</div>';
    if(growlsList.length >= 5){
    //you seemed to want to keep the growl count to 5. this removes the last one.
      $(growlsList[growlsList.length -1]).remove();
    }
      growlDiv.prepend(html);
      $(":first", growlDiv).triggerHandler("growlHideShow");
    }
```